# C# Read all bytes from file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, hex, byte

Here is what i want to do. I have txt file with HEX value. Like this: `08-08-CE-FE-CC-D1-05-00-01-00-47-72-50-6F-69-6E-74-30-31`. Then i want read these bytes and do operations like this:

```
byte[] newArray = { bytes[5], bytes[6], bytes[7], bytes[8], bytes[9], bytes[10], bytes[11], bytes[12] };
double newData = (BitConverter.ToDouble(newArray, 0) * 180);
```

I have tried `StreamReader` but it always reads my file like string.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have file with string content (that represents bytes in hexa format) than you can read it as string ant then convert it to bytes using this:

```
 var hexaStringFromFile = "08-08-CE-FE-CC-D1-05-00-01-00-47-72-50-6F-69-6E-74-30-31";
 var bytes = hexaStringFromFile.Split('-')
     .Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16))
     .ToList();
```